# Stream video via AirPlay without affecting app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, airplay, apple-tv

I have a native app and would like to stream video to an Apple TV over AirPlay, but without affecting the app screen. The video should NOT to be shown on the app screen -- only on the Apple TV.

Is this possible in iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [it is possible](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html):

> If you use AirPlay to allow users to redirect content to an external
>   device display, you can either mirror the current app content on the
>   second display or show different content on it.